# Upload an image to a MongoDB database with Vue, TypeScript, Express and Multer

Tags: typescript, mongodb, vue.js, express, multer

I'm trying to upload an image to my database, but I'm not quite sure if I'm doing this right.

I have this code in my child component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';

const movieTitle = ref("");
const moviePoster = ref();

function fileInput(e: Event) {
    const inputElement = e.target as HTMLInputElement;

    const file = inputElement.files?.[0].name;
    if (file) {
        moviePoster.value = file;
        console.log("moviePoster", moviePoster.value);
    }
}

const emits = defineEmits<{ (e: "movieInfo", poster: FormData, title: string): void }>();

function emitImage() {
    if (!moviePoster.value) {
        return;
    }

    // Emit the "movieInfo" event with the poster and title
    emits("movieInfo", moviePoster.value, movieTitle.value);
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="large-container">
    <div class="small-container">
        <form @submit.prevent="emitImage" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="file">Ladda up film poster</label>
            <input type="file" @change="fileInput"/>
            <label for="movie-title-input">Film titel</label>
            <input type="text" v-model="movieTitle" name="movie-title-input" />
            <button>Upload image</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

In my parent component I have this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    import AdminPageVue from '@/components/adminpage/AdminPage.vue';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { ref } from 'vue';

    const savedMovie = ref<any>(null);

    async function saveMovieInfo(poster: FormData, movieTitle: string) {

        console.log("poster", poster, "title", movieTitle);

        const movieInfo = {
            poster: JSON.stringify(poster),
            title: movieTitle
        };

        console.log("movieInfo", movieInfo);

        try {
            const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/movie/savemovie", movieInfo);
            console.log("Movie saved successfully!", response.data);

            const { poster, title } = response.data;

            console.log("poster", poster)

            savedMovie.value = {
                poster: poster,
                title: title,
            };

            console.log("savedMovie.value", savedMovie.value)

            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Failed to save movie:", error);
        }
    }
</script>

<template>
    <div>
      <AdminPageVue @movieInfo="saveMovieInfo"></AdminPageVue>
        <img :src="savedMovie.poster" alt="Uploaded Image" v-if="savedMovie" /> 
    </div>
</template>
```

Then in my express server I have a mongoose schema which looks like this:

```
const { default: mongoose } = require("mongoose");

const storedMovieInfo = mongoose.Schema({
    poster: String,
    title: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("storedmovieinfo", storedMovieInfo);
```

Then there is the movie.js router:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const multer = require("multer");
const MovieModel = require ("../models/movie_model");

const upload = multer({storage});

router.post('/savemovie', upload.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
    const { title, poster } = req.body;
  
    const parsedPoster = JSON.parse(poster);
  
    console.log('poster', parsedPoster, 'title', title);
  
    try {
      const newMovie = await MovieModel.create({
        poster: parsedPoster,
        title: title,
      });
  
      console.log("newMovie", newMovie);
  
      res.status(201).json({
        poster: newMovie.poster,
        title: newMovie.title,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error saving movie:", error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to save movie" });
    }
  });

module.exports = router;
```

For what I can see, it takes the name of the uploaded image and store that in the database, but when I retrieve it back to the client and want to interpolate it, the browser can't find the image, which makes me think that I'm doing something wrong.

I've tried to save the image to the database to be able to retrieve it from there, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to send binary data to backend using `FormData` and let backend handle the data.

In child component:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';

const movieTitle = ref("");
const moviePoster = ref<File>();


const fileInput = (e: Event): void => {
  const inputElement = <HTMLInputElement>e.target;

  const file = inputElement.files?.[0];

  if (file) {
    moviePoster.value = file;
  }
}

const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: "movieInfo", poster: File, title: string): void
}>();

const emitImage = () => {
  if (!moviePoster.value) {
    return;
  }

  // Emit the "movieInfo" event with the poster and title
  emit("movieInfo", moviePoster.value, movieTitle.value);
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="large-container">
    <div class="small-container">
      <form @submit.prevent="emitImage" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file">Ladda up film poster</label>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" @change="fileInput"/>
        <label for="movie-title-input">Film titel</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="movieTitle" name="movie-title-input" />
        <button>Upload image</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And in Parent component:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import axios from 'axios';
import { ref } from 'vue';

import FileUploader from 'components/FileUploader.vue';

const savedMovie = ref<any>(null);

const saveMovieInfo = async (moviePoster: File, movieTitle: string) => {

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('poster', moviePoster);
  formData.append('title', movieTitle);


  try {
    const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/movie/savemovie", formData);
    console.log("Movie saved successfully!", response.data);

    const { poster, title } = response.data;

    console.log("poster", poster)

    savedMovie.value = {
      poster: poster,
      title: title,
    };

    console.log("savedMovie.value", savedMovie.value)


  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Failed to save movie:", error);
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <FileUploader @movieInfo="saveMovieInfo"></FileUploader>
    <img :src="savedMovie.poster" alt="Uploaded Image" v-if="savedMovie" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Your backend should return either the base64 encoded string of image or a url(usually an s3) where the image is stored which can be passed directly in `src` attribute as you already did in parent component as `:src="savedMovie.poster"`

Comment: Thank you! With your help I managed to save the image to a folder in the server. Now I just have to save it to the database